# What am I doing wrong? Adding 1 to use input

Tags: python

Having some difficulty with this problem. The program should get a number from the user. It will be the amount of triangles. The first triangle should have two rows. Each new triangle will have one extra row than the last triangle.
This is what I have:

```
numTri = input('Please umber of triangles: ')
numTri = eval(numTri)
numRow = 2
x = 0
while j<numTri:
   y = '*'
   z = 0
   while z<numRow:
         print y
         y = y + *
         z  += 1
    x += 1
    numRow += 1
```

Getting an invalid syntax error on the print line. Not sure if I'm doing anything else wrong. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: `numTri = eval(numTri)` NOOOOOOO

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: Beat me to it!

Comment: y = y + * is suspicious as well

Comment: What is your Python version? What is the output of `python -V`?

Comment: We keep seeing this pattern input+eval recently. Is someone teaching this?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using Python 3, there is a lot of errors in your code. Let us see them:

## Major problems

**The `j` variable**

You use a `j` variable,  in the loop condition, which is not set neither used anywhere. This will result in an error:

```
while j<numTri:
```

I believe you want to use the `x` variable:

```
while x<numTri:
```

**`print()` is a function**

In Python 3, you should put the parameters of a `print()` function between parenthesis, which is not the  case:

```
         print y
```

Too easy to solve:

```
         print(y)
```

Note that the parenthesis are optional in Python 2.

**`'*'` char without quotes:**

You try to append the `'*'` char to the string from `y` but does not enclose the char with quotes:

```
         y = y + *
```

The interpreter will see this asterisk as the multiplication operator, which will yield an error. Just enclose it with quotes (single or double, it does not matter):

```
        y = y + '*'
```

**Indentation problem**

A specially pernicious problem in your code is that, after the second `while` loop, your code does not return to the same indentation level of the loop. I replaced the spaces below with [open boxes](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2423/index.htm) so we can count them:

```
␣␣␣while z<numRow:
␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣print y
␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣y = y + *
␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣z  += 1
␣␣␣␣x += 1
␣␣␣␣numRow += 1
```

Alas, there is one more space in the two last lines when compared with the `while` line. You should remove those spurious spaces.

A resulting code will be:

```
numTri = input('Please umber of triangles: ')
numTri = eval(numTri)
numRow = 2
x = 0
while x<numTri:
   y = '*'
   z = 0
   while z<numRow:
         print(y)
         y = y + '*'
         z  += 1
   x += 1
   numRow += 1
```

## Minor problems

There are also some other details in your code which would be considered *bad practices*. Those will not matter a lot to you *yet*, since you are *really* novice, but we can explore some of them.

**Avoiding `eval()`**

`eval()` is a powerful yet risky function, so we avoid using it. It is specially easy to do in your case, since `int()` will convert the read string to an integer without problems:

```
numTri = input('Please umber of triangles: ')
numTri = int(numTri)
```

**Non-standard indentation**

Sometimes, you indent what is inside your loops with four spaces:

```
␣␣␣y = '*'
␣␣␣z = 0
␣␣␣while z<numRow:
```

then with six spaces

```
   ␣␣␣␣␣␣print(y)
   ␣␣␣␣␣␣y = y + '*'
   ␣␣␣␣␣␣z  += 1
```

and even with four spaces, which results in an error:

```
␣␣␣␣x += 1
␣␣␣␣numRow += 1
```

The best thing to do is to always use the same indentation size. [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (a set of recommendations for all Python programmers) recommends to use four spaces for each indentation:

```
␣␣␣␣y = '*'
␣␣␣␣z = 0
␣␣␣␣while z<numRow:
    ␣␣␣␣print(y)
    ␣␣␣␣y = y + '*'
    ␣␣␣␣z  += 1
␣␣␣␣x += 1
␣␣␣␣numRow += 1
```

**`while` instead of `for`**

This one is hard stuff for novices, but it may be helpful to point nonetheless. Your code would be much better if you used [`for`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) loops with the [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#range) function:

```
for x in range(0, numTri+1):
    y = '*'
    for z in range(0, numRow+1):
        print(y)
        y = y + '*'
    numRow += 1
```

However, as you are a student, I believe you will learn about this feature some time in the future, so take it easy :)

The resulting code:

```
numTri = input('Please umber of triangles: ')
numTri = int(numTri)
numRow = 2
for x in range(0, numTri+1):
    y = '*'
    for z in range(0, numRow+1):
        print(y)
        y = y + '*'
    numRow += 1
```

Comment: Putting "avoid evaluating user input with `eval`" under "minor problems" is probably something that causes lots of people to cringe ;)

Answer (score 1):

But I think the syntax error (and thus answering your question) is because you are using Python 3 where `print` needs round brackets. So :

```
print ( y )
```

And if you just want the highest grade for your programming task:

```
print('\n'.join('*'*y for x in range(int(input('Please umber of triangles: '))) for y in range(1,x+3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`j` is never defined before you reach the `while` loop. Maybe you meant `while x < numTri:` instead?

Also, the

```
x = 0
while x < numTri:
    # do something
    x += 1
```

construct is not very Pythonic; try

```
for x in range(numTri):
    # do something
```

instead.

Comment: Then you should also use `for z in range(numRow):`

Answer (score 0):

```
numTri = int(raw_input('Please umber of triangles: '))
```

or on python 3.x

```
numTri = int(input('Please umber of triangles: '))
```